# I'm trying to delete a node from list with the least value, but i have problems with rebuilding a link between nodes

Tags: c++, list

As I said i want to delete from list node with minimal value, to do that i have second function(which works) and it just returns an int, which is a minimal node value in a list. I'm passing this int to the function which should search list for this value and delete a node which contains it, but i have problem with rebuilding a link between previous value and a next value(previous and next nodes from deleted node). I know that this is the problem because when I try to display list I get some trash value. What do  I do wrong or what should I add to correctly rebuild a link between these list nodes?

### Edge class in a nutshell

```
class Edge
{
private:

    int _StartVertice;
    int _EndVertice;
    int _weight;
    Edge* _NextEdge;

public:

    Edge() :_StartVertice(0), _EndVertice(0), _weight(0), _NextEdge(nullptr) {};
  
    const int& get_Weight() const { return _weight; };

    Edge* get_NextEdge() { return _NextEdge; };

    void set_NextEdge(Edge* NextEdge) { _NextEdge = new Edge;  _NextEdge = NextEdge; };
};
```

---

### Function in a List where head is an Edge type

```
  void Edge_List::Delete_Minimal_Weight_Edge(int min_weight)
            {
            Edge* tmp = new Edge;
            tmp = head;
            Edge* prev = head;
        
        
                while (tmp->get_NextEdge()->get_Weight() != min_weight)
                {   
                        prev = tmp;
                        tmp = tmp->get_NextEdge();      
                }
        
                prev = tmp;
                tmp = tmp->get_NextEdge();
        
                prev->set_NextEdge(tmp);
                
                delete tmp;
        
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop ends one iteration before the node I want to delete so I have to iterate the prev and tmp node one more time, then the link needs to be rebuilt with the next node from tmp so iterating to the next node is once again needed.

```
void Edge_List::Delete_Minimal_Weight_Edge(int min_weight)
{
    Edge* tmp = new Edge;
    tmp = head;
    Edge* prev = head;


    while (tmp->get_NextEdge() != nullptr && tmp->get_NextEdge()->get_Weight() <= min_weight)
    {
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->get_NextEdge();
    }
    prev = tmp;
    tmp = tmp->get_NextEdge();

    prev->set_NextEdge(tmp->get_NextEdge());

    delete tmp;
}
```

Comment: Try the solution above

Comment: It didn't work, but I found a solution, but thank you for your help anyway ^^

Comment: I posted the solution